# Android studio bumblebee unicode font issue (Bengali/Bangla)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

All of a sudden my android studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1 Patch 2) broke all unicode characters (bangla). Although in application it is showing correctly, in github it's showing correctly. even yesterday it was correct with android studio also. I am adding some image below to show exactly differences,
This is how it's looking in Android Studio,
[image]

This is how it should Look,
[image]

My OS: Windows 12.

As for some reason, images are not loading here, I will write it down. There are mixed letters in Bangla language, and all those mixed are breaking.

For example, below words are in correct format

```
স্বামী-স্ত্রী (mixed letters example).
```

But same words are shown like this in android studio,

```
স্আমি - স্ত্ই
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem. There were issue with default selected font with android studio. Off course I still don't understand root cause, still this fixes my issue.

Previously I using Jetbrains Mono (default font with my android Studio), this one and many other font with android studio is breaking Bangla words. If switched to Nirmala UI/Kalpurush font, then no breaking.

UPDATE: with newer update (patch 3), this issue fixed automatically. Jetbrains Mono font works also.